# Notes on the side of beamer slides

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I found nice package `pgfpages` which allows to add notes on the side of existing beamer slides. However I want to remove two additional mini screens that come up on the top of the second screen. Does anyone know how to remove them? See picture below.[image]

The following output is desired! 
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

A frame.
\note{Two mini screen boxes above are not needed. How to remove them? Only this text box is needed.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). What do you have so far?

Comment: (1) read the `pgfpages` manual and the source code. There are golds in comments. (2) declare a layout consisting of two logical pages; one is from the shipout routine and the other is empty. (3) use `\pgfpagesshipoutlogicalpage` to push notes to the empty logical page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can format the notepage in any way you want by modifying the respective beamer template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\setbeamertemplate{note page}{\insertnote}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

A frame.
\note{Two mini screen boxes above are not needed. How to remove them? Only this text box is needed.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: wow! that's mazing and so quick! thanks a lot @samcarter!!!